# Tensorflow object detection training

Tags: image, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, image-segmentation

I would like to detect objects (upper half of the image below) in images (bottom half). Is it smart to train the dataset with images in a different scale (or size)? Or shall I train it with parts of the bottom half of the image below? What is the best way to mark the objects for training?

Kind regards

[image: example training]

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want in detail?

Comment: Let me try: I would like to detect objects in pictures like the picture below (the objects are really small). For training the dataset I only have those objects in another scale (close-up). Now I was wondering if I can detect these big objects (training data) in pictures with small objects and another scale.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to detect small objects in images but your training data consist of objects having bigger size.

Comment: exactly! :-) Is that possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. If you are exclusively interested in detecting objects at roughly the scale of the below picture, your training data should consist of images like the below one. To add on: try to get at least a decent range of sizes around the bottom so as to avoid small deviations from a specific scale throwing it off, but generally you should be fine.